# Hover tooltip on specific words in rich text box?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to create something like a tooltip suddenly hoovering over the mouse pointer when specific words in the richt text box is hovered over. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use MouseMove and then GetCharIndexFromPosition to determine which character the mouse is over, then display the associated tooltop.